# Almost sure convergence of sum of independent Bernoulli and other random variables

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $W_n$ be a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables with
>
> $$
> P(W_n = 1) = 1 - P(W_n = 0) = \frac{1}{n^2}
> $$
>
> Let $Y_n$ be a sequence of independent real-valued random variables with
>
> $$
> EY_n = 0
> $$
>
> and
>
> $$
> EY_n^2 = n^2
> $$
>
> Assume that $Y_n$ and $W_n$ are independent. Show that
>
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n W_i Y_i
> $$
>
> is almost surely convergent.

I'm quite stumped by this. Immediately I assumed Khintchin-Kolmogorov might work but the variances are not summable. Then I attempted Borel-Cantelli using Markovs inequality but the resulting bound is too weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by the Botel-Cantelli lemma the probability that $W_i \ne 0$ infinitely often is zero, i.e. the sum over all $W_i Y_i$ is almost surely only a finite sum. This implies almost sure convergence.